# What is the file "fred.9113"?

Tags: networking

```
execve("/usr/sbin/named", ["named", "-t", "/var/lib/named/etc/bind/", "-u", "bind", "-f", "-g", "-d", "9", "-E"], ["TERM=xterm", "LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio="..., "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin", "LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8", "HOME=/home/michael", "DISPLAY=localhost:10.0", "SHELL=/bin/bash", "LOGNAME=root", "USER=root", "USERNAME=root", "MAIL=/var/mail/root", "SUDO_COMMAND=/usr/bin/strace -o fred -ff -v -s 512 named -t /var/lib/named/etc/bind/ -u bind -f -g -d 9 -E", "SUDO_USER=michael", "SUDO_UID=1000", "SUDO_GID=1000"]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x21873000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb77f1000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_dev=makedev(8, 3), st_ino=84, st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_nlink=1, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_blksize=4096, st_blocks=48, st_size=22937, st_atime=2016/07/24-20:24:11, st_mtime=2016/07/24-20:24:11, st_ctime=2016/07/24-20:24:11}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 22937, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xb77eb000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/liblwres.so.80", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
@
@
@
@
@
@
@
@
@
@
@
@
@
@
```

Answer (score 3):

It contains the output of the command

```
/usr/bin/strace -o fred -ff -v -s 512 named -t /var/lib/named/etc/bind/ -u bind -f -g -d 9 -E
```

for the process with PID 9113

Comment: Thanks. I didn't run strace. What's happened? Who can do it? I found this file in my home directory.

Comment: Where did you get the strace log in your question? The first line shows that user `michael` run that command using `sudo`, most likely when he was logged in via ssh.